# Cannot pass jQuery object.method to another function to be executed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following JavaScript:

```
function MyMethod(func)
{
  func();
}

$('#Btn').on('click', function(e)
{
  e.preventDefault();

  var form = $(this).parent();

  MyMethod(form.submit);
});
```

http://codepen.io/chrisnicholson/pen/YGxOdJ

This doesn't work, giving the following error in Chrome:

**jquery.min.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'trigger' of undefined**

If I modify the call to `MyMethod` to use the following then it works:

```
MyMethod(function(){
  form.submit();
});
```

http://codepen.io/chrisnicholson/pen/amyRXX

Can someone explain why this is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, good ol' binding of `this` at work! If you only provide the method, it will not be called on the form but on the global object, like

```
submit.call(window) // resp. undefined in strict mode. Hence the error, I guess.
```

where what you want is

```
submit.call(form)
```

One way to fix this: [Bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) the submit method to the form:

```
MyMethod(form.submit.bind(form));
```

Comment: Is this complete? He is passing $form.submit instead of $form.get(0).submit - I cannot test my idea because a plugin is adding stuff to the forms

Answer (score 0):

Your code be. Just pass the object is enough.

```
function MyMethod(formSubmit)
{
  formSubmit.submit();
}

$('#Btn').on('click', function(e)
{
  e.preventDefault();

  var form = $(this).parent();

  MyMethod(form);
})
```

Comment: That ties `MyMethod` strictly to forms. In my case (a dialog box) I simply want to execute the function passed to it, not necessarily a form object. It's my bad, I shouldn't have named the parameter `formSubmit`, instead simply `func`, I'll update my code.

Answer (score -1):

Without the parentheses, .submit would just be a property of the jQuery object that you have.  In this instance, your form.

Adding the parentheses actually calls the .submit() method on the form object.